Did Kant actually read Aristotle or did he just become aware of it indirectly through commentators?
I had a teacher who mentioned in passing that Kant never read Aristotle. I've also heard this on other occasions. Did Kant actually read Aristotle or did he just become aware of it indirectly through commentators?

Maybe the role of the "encycopedic" philosphy of Christian Wolff has been relevant, mainly for logic

Indirect source: "As is well known, the script used by Kant for his logic lectures is Georg Friedrich Meier’s Auszüge aus der Vernunftlehre (Extract from the Doctrine of Reason)".

See into Kant's Introduction to Logic (1800) the well-known passage: "Logic, as we have it, is derived from Aristotle's Analytic.
This philosopher may be regarded as the father of Logic. He
treated it as an Organon, and divided it into Analytic and
Dialectic. [...] Since Aristotle's time Logic has not gained much in extent,
as indeed its nature forbids that it should." 1/2

And also "The general Logic of Wolff is the best we possess. Some have combined it with the Aristotelian, as, for example, Reusch. Baumgarten, a man who has in this respect much merit, abridged Wolff's Logic, and Meyer then commented on
Baumgarten." 2/2

My disclaimer is I'm not a Kant scholar, but what I could dig up given my small Kant collection and online resources seems to suggest that it is not a historical fact that Kant read Aristotle extensively or in the Greek.
Seems a suspect claim to say that Kant did not read any Aristotle. It seems more likely to say that he never read it in the Greek and what he read was through others, since he was trained thoroughly in Latin which besides German, was the dominant language of Germans. He would have had exposure to Hebrew and Greek, as it was typically taught to prepare students for Bible studies. Here Kant's Philosophical Development (SEP) says:

Physics was acceptable as long as its findings did not undermine the Bible. As independent research programs, however, the sciences were deemed wellsprings of heresy.8 Standard curriculum included a heavy dose of theology, catechism memorization and biblical stories. Although the school did offer a variety of topics: Latin, Greek, Hebrew, logic, history (both church and philosophy) and geography, the primary use of this instruction was in preparation for further theological study at the university.

I can find no confirmation that Kant (bibliography.com) did NOT read Aristotle. In fact, Kant was brought up among pietists and then had training in theology. In fact, the bibliographic article states:

While at school, Kant gained a deep appreciation for the Latin classics... In 1740, Kant enrolled at the University of Konigsberg as a theology student, but was soon attracted to mathematics and physics.

It's hard to imagine him having no exposure to Aristotle either as budding Christian or a natural philosopher. Combined with the fact that Kant became a lecturer in philosophy and was a commentator and philosopher of logic going so far as to write Introduction to Logic (GB) and comment on Aristotle's syllogisms. In fact, Kant directly attributed philosophical positions to Aristotle, according to Dyck's "The “Aristotle of Königsberg”?: Kant and the Aristotelian Mind" (PhilPapers.org)
Furthermore, we have confirmation In Introduction to Logic on page 10 he says:

Logic, as we have it, is derived from Aristotle's Analytic. This philosopher may be regarded as the father of Logic... His treatment is very scholastic... Of this, however, we can make no use, since almost everything ends in mere subtilties... Aristotle has omitted no essential point of the understanding; we have only become more accurate, methodical, and orderly.

This seems to be a commentary on the works of Aristotle directly, and the SEP takes the position in Aristotle's Logic (SEP) that "Kant thought that Aristotle had discovered everything there was to know about logic".
Prior Analytics became available in Latin at least 500 years before Kant, and the Scholastics made much use of his ideas. Aristotle, in fact, worked prominently into the theological debates between the Lutherans and Catholics of the day, and Kant was raised Lutheran. From WP:

The so-called Anonymus Aurelianensis III from the second half of the twelfth century is the first extant Latin commentary, or rather fragment of a commentary.

But I can find confirmation (as a non-Kant scholar), that Kant's knowledge of Greek philosophy is controversial. Here, is a Kant scholar on Research Gate who says so in his abstract for his paper "Kant’s Confrontation with Plato and the Greek World in the Inaugural Dissertation" (ResearchGate.net):

The discussion concerning Kant’s knowledge of the Greek world has long been a subject of debate. Our contribution is intended to show that in the Dissertation of 1770 Kant is measured against some currents of Greek thought, and above all with Plato, on topics which will become very important in the articulated development of criticism in the 1770s. One aspect of our analysis deals with the texts that could have filtered Kant’s knowledge of ancient Greek tradition.

Thus, it seems reasonable to conclude that at a minimum there is no definitive proof that Kant was trained in the Greek classics like a modern classicist; the Scholastics were Catholics and relied on Aristotle is a fact, but Latin was the lingua franca. Therefore, much of what Kant read of Aristotle, though he had some familiarity with Greek and Hebrew, was indirect through the commentaries and translations of other scholars, and what he did read of Aristotle was likely in Latin.

@KristianBerry Considering that the first scholarly,  critical editions with Greek side-to-side and direct translations are rather 20th-century than anything earlier, I guess it is pretty safe to say that Kant did not read Aristotle in the same way we do these days.

As quoted by Conifold:

Kant mentions Aristotle and Aristotelian philosophers only a hundred times in all of his works (printed and manuscript). This is not so much if we think that most of the times they are cursory references or are contradictory and ambiguous... We must confess openly that concerning these kinds of sources we have no evidence in other sources that Kant read Aristotelian works, nor do the textbooks he used during his lessons testify to a good knowledge of Aristotelian tradition.

Sgarbi, Kant and Aristotle, p.3

+1 You can hit 40,000 in the reputation leagues with this strategy!
